# Filter Python 2D Array based on 2nd Element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a python 2D array like this:

```
array = [('aaa', 20), ('bbb', 30), ('ccc', 40), ('ddd', 50)]
```

I want to filter this array based on the 2nd value in each set.
for example I want to keep only the items having the **2nd item >= 40**

**Expected output:**

```
filtered_array =  [('ccc', 40), ('ddd', 50)]
```

I can achieve this with loops but is there an elegant way of filtering this?

Comment: ``[i for i in array if i[1]>=40]``

Comment: Thanks, it still uses for loop though.

Comment: Well, I can't think of a logical way, that would make this possible.  You need to check every elements' second element. How do you think that is possible without looping over every element?

Comment: You have a list of tuples, not a 2D array.

Comment: Why the `numpy` tag if you don't have a numpy array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Clearest:

```
[x for x in xs if x[1] >= 40]
```

Less clear:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x[1] >= 40, xs))
```

No loops at the Python level:

```
def f(xs):
    try:
        x = next(xs)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    if x[1] >= 40:
        yield x
    yield from f(xs)

list(f(iter(xs)))
```

Comment: Whoops, I always forget about the order even after knowing a bit of Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`, but under the hood, it still uses a loop, because how else?

```
list(filter(lambda x: x[1] >= 40, array))
#[('ccc', 40), ('ddd', 50)]
```

Or you can use `itertools.filterfalse` (with the same footnote):

```
list(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x[1] < 40, array))
#[('ccc', 40), ('ddd', 50)]
```